# Automatically add hidden text into selection

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I "force" browser include a hidden text into selection?
For example:

```js
const map = {
  " ": "·",
  "\t": "→",
  "\r\n": "↵\r\n",
  "\n": "␤\n",
  "\r": "␍\r"
};
const whiteSpaces = t => t.replace(/(\r\n|[ \t\r\n])/g, a => map[a]);
expectedHead.textContent += " " + expected.textContent.length + " chars";
expected.textContent = whiteSpaces(expected.textContent);
document.addEventListener("selectionchange", e =>
{
  const string = getSelection().toString();
  selectedHead.textContent = "selected " + string.length + " chars";
  selected.textContent = whiteSpaces(string);
  result.textContent = selected.textContent === expected.textContent;
    
});
```

```css
x-hidden
{
  font-size: 0;
  white-space: pre;
  display: inline-block; 
}

pre
{
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0;
}

th
{
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
.container
{
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
body
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>select text below:</div>
<div class="container"><div><x-hidden>hidden1 </x-hidden>visible1</div>
<div><x-hidden>v</x-hidden>1.2.3<x-hidden>
    </x-hidden></div>
<div><x-hidden>    hidden2</x-hidden> visible2<x-hidden> hidden3</x-hidden></div></div>

<table border="1">
<tr>
<th id="expectedHead">expected</th><th id="selectedHead">selected</th><th>as expected?</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><pre><mark id="expected">hidden1 visible1
v1.2.3
    
    hidden2 visible2 hidden3</mark></pre></td>
<td><pre><mark id="selected"></mark></pre></td>
<td id="result"></td>
</tr></table>
```

In this example it's very difficult select text exactly as in expected column and get `true` in the last column because first `hidden1` and last `hidden3` strings can only be selected by placing cursor outside of the text.

Is there a way detect when a text in a specific node is fully selected and if that node has siblings `x-hidden` elements, force content of these elements into selection?

Comment: I am able to select the text as expected, but it requires knowing to select extra on both beginning and end.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? E.g. are you trying to affect text copied from the page? If so, there may be alternative ways to achieve the same result.